# I am getting all anchor links instead of specific link in scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using **scrapy 1.0.3**. Here is my code of spider file,

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from parser_xxx.items import XxxItem

class XxxSpider(Spider):
    name = "xxx"
    allowed_domains = ["xxx.xxx.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://xxx.xxx.com/jobs/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        quelist = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@id="job_listings"]')
        for que in quelist:
           item = XxxItem()
           item['title'] = que.xpath('//a//h4/text()').extract()
           item['link']  = que.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
           yield item
```

But, I am getting all anchor links and all titles. Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your XPath expressions *context-specific* by prepending a dot. Plus, I think you should iterate over the links inside the `div` with `id="job_listings"`:

```
quelist = response.xpath('//div[@id="job_listings"]//a')
for que in quelist:
   item = XxxItem()

   item['title'] = que.xpath('.//h4/text()').extract()
   item['link']  = que.xpath('@href').extract()

   yield item
```

Comment: @MayurKoshti glad to help. Also note that you can use the `response.xpath()` shortcut here.